# Ansible - roles and tasks execution handling in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am working on ansible exception handling tasks and stuck in an ansible tasks execution handling problem where I need your guide to come over.

I have 2 system host group **system_a** and **system_b** and I develop 6 roles and each role have multiple tasks.

I execute 2 roles on **syste_a** and reaming 4 on **system_b**.

in my case is,  if any tasks in a role(1-6) are failed then skip the remains role execution and execution one task end of the playbook on system_a group host. How can handle this case in ansible.

Can you help me in this situation?

here is my site.yml

```
            - host: system_a
              roles:
                  - role-1
                  - role-2
            - hosts: system_b
              roles:
                  - role-3
                  - role-4
                  - role-5
                  - role-6
            - tasks:
                  - name: restart postfix service
                    service: name=postfix state=restarted           
                    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
                    loop: "{{ groups['system_a'] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ignore_error:true
```

This and some other options mentioned in [this doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html) might be what you are looking for.